# Is eating human corpses good for my diet? Are there any drawbacks?

Tags: scum

In the game [SCUM](https://store.steampowered.com/app/513710/SCUM/) I've came across puppets (the equivalent of zombies) and realized recently you can cut them up and cook the meat.

Doing so seems to have almost no draw backs besides it being high in sodium? What (if any) draw backs are there, and why don't I see more people eating humans?

Comment: HNQ, here we come!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were no drawbacks for eating <strike>zombie</strike> Puppet meat in SCUM. The caveat being that it had to be placed on a skewer for consummation and could not be cooked or consumed outright.

According to SCUM's [Wikia page](https://scum-game.fandom.com/wiki/Cooking) on Cooking:

> "[Small Skewer with Meat] can be crafted with Puppet Meat and cooked with no ill ailments or side effects, for an easy source of protein early game."

However, as of [patch 0.1.19.20050](https://games-guides.com/scum-patch-notes-0-1-19-10050-changelog-november-2/) from November 2nd, 2018 Puppets can no longer be chopped into meat or fat. If you somehow manage to acquire Puppet meat you should be able to consume it without repercussions, but it should now be impossible to get.